# How to gain Turn Undead class feature without taking a cleric or paladin level?

Tags: character-creation, optimization, dnd-3e

I'd thinking of building a zealot-type character, who would use Divine Feats to bolster his combat. To fuel those feats I need Turn Undead attempts per day. The normal way of getting them is having at least one cleric level or 4 paladin levels and a non-disastrous Charisma.

However, I intend to take a base class different from those and would like to level it as high as possible. As a non-human, I'd rather avoid dipping, since that pesky XP penalty will hinder my advance.

How can I obtain Turn attempts/day without committing to a base class? Prestige Classes are an option that I would rather avoid, but could do (since they don't bring XP penalties) as long as they don't require me having another base class as well (which does bring XP penalties).

We are specifically playing 3e. Material for related editions may be acceptable, but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't until *Dragon* #309 that the magazine switched to publishing *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* material, so if the creature has a patron deity, the creature meets the prerequisites of the general feat God Touched (*Dragon* #305 42) and that feat, in turn, meets the prerequisite of the feat Divine Channeler (*Dragon* #305 42). This latter feat enables such a creature once per day to turn or rebuke undead as cleric of half the character's level.

From there one uses the *Arms and Equipment Guide* rules for Magic Items that Grant Feats (128) to fashion a custom item that grants the feat Extra Turning (*Defenders of the Faith* 20), perhaps multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In the book Sword & Scorcery: path of the sword- Variant Classes (Ghost Hunter) there is an oprion to let the Monk have turn undead ability.
In short it Works like the normal feature of the cleric, however the monk is not allowed any feats to improve his turning abilities, without having the correct class. The Level will however stack.
This came at a cost of the fortitde save being reduced to that of the rogue class ( base save).

Something like this could possibly work for any class...who knows.