# What feats and magic items can I use to boost my speed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, optimization

I am playing a 3.5 game with liberal inspiration from Pathfinder (we have Combat Maneuver Bonus/Defense, for example), and even heavier amounts of homebrew. Thanks to extremely high-powered homebrew classes, quest rewards, and worshiping the god of the healthy body, I can move 150 ft per round, or run 750 ft thanks to the Run feat, and essentially "flash step" another 900 feet on top of that (but everyone in this world can do that, so it's no big deal). I calculate this to be about 190 miles per hour, given six second rounds, and I'm interested in seeing if I can break the sound barrier (about 750 miles per hour).

What magic items or feats are available to a character in either 3.5 or Pathfinder to boost their speed? I already have *haste* and *expeditious retreat* on me thanks to perks from worshipping the right gods and from permanent runes I received as a quest reward, and I already have the Run feat. I also want to achieve this speed by myself, so no outside assistance by cohorts or PC spellcasters. I am an 11th level gestalt between a Swordsage and a homebrew class called a [Tenken](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Tenken,_Tome_(3.5e_Class)). I'm planning on taking Master of 9 for the swordsage soon. Currently, I can take an extra turn 1/encounter with the Tenken, and at 20th I get the extra turn every round, so I don't want to sacrifice anything to multiclassing. I am a homebrew race called the Aericetus, which has

> +6 dex, +6 Int, -2 str, -2 con, Swim Speed, Darkvision 300ft, Sneak Attack+1d6, Spellfire: Absorb spell energy directed at you and return fire

Comment: May be a duplicate of this [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14505/8610), but your circumstances might make this different enough.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect your actual question - it's completely different to a "fastest PC alive" question, and hopefully this will prevent people misunderstanding.

Comment: @Axoren Answer-like material hidden away in comments makes it harder for future readers with this problem from finding the solution to their problem; that becomes especially true as time goes on and there are more posts and more comments. Please use an answer post to post a fleshed-out answer instead.

Comment: Considering the amount, and strength, of the homebrew, why should this question not be answered with similar material?

Comment: @Chemus Because anyone could trivially say "Here's my homebrew magic item that costs 1 gp and lets you teleport and increases your speed like infinity times over and gives you permanent undispellable improved haste and can only be used by your specific character build. It's the best option!" There's no practical limits to homebrew; Without such limits, this becomes an idea-generation question, and we don't handle those well.

Answer (score 4):

I am largely uninterested in how similar results can be achieved in *Pathfinder*, so I've narrowed this to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*. I am also uninterested in changing forms, but I assume doing so adds significantly to these totals; I'll leave that exercise to another. This was exercise enough. Undoubtedly, there are bits and pieces here and there that can add to these totals, and already using *haste*, *expeditious retreat*, and the homebrew class are significant.

## *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* feats that increase land speed

There are a lot. Like Sturgeon's Law says, most of them are terrible. Note that some of these feats were originally printed prior to the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* revision and may be subject to minor adjustments by the DM (*DMG* 4). I'm pretty sure none grant enhancement bonuses so they should all be usable while the *expeditious retreat* spell's duration continues. The following list is alphabetical.

- The general feat **Altered State** (*Dragon* #332 84) allows a creature that takes 1d6 days to be dealt 1d4 points of Wisdom damage and make a level check (DC 20). Success means that the creature can take 10 min. to make a Handle Animal skill check (DC 20). Success means that for 1 day/level the creature gains a +10 ft. bonus to its land speed and a +2 bonus on Initiative checks. The DM may limit this feat's availability to barbarians.
- The domain feat **Animal Devotion** (*Complete Champion* 54-5) grants the creature at least 1/day the ability to take a swift action to gain for 1 min. a +5 ft. bonus to its speed that's +10 ft. at level 4, +15 ft. at level 8, +20 ft. at level 12, +25 ft. at level 16, and +30 ft. at level 20. Enjoy being covered in black spots. [Gaining the ability to turn undead without taking cleric levels is a thing.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65336/8610)
- The general feat **Bind Vestige** (*Tome of Magic* 72-3) and **Improved Bind Vestige** (*TM* 74) allow the creature to bind an inferior version of the vestige Ronove, that thereupon grants a +10 ft. bonus to the creature's base land speed.
- The wild feat **Cheetah’s Speed** (*Complete Divine* 79) grants the creature the ability to spend a use of wild shape to for 1 hour change its base land speed to 50 ft. Further, 1/hour, the creature during a charge can move at *ten times* its speed. A generous DM may allow this to be combined with the general feat **Savage Mobility** (*Dragon* #326 33) for another +10 ft. bonus to land speed. [Gaining wild shape without taking druid levels is a thing.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84392/8610)
- The general feat **Dash** (*Complete Warrior* 97) grants the creature a +5 ft. bonus to its speed.
- Probably something can be done with the tactical feat **Faith Unswerving** (*Tome of Battle* 34-5) and its tactical maneuver keep up the pressure, which allows a creature to take an immediate action before the creature's next turn and after a successful attack's made during a charge to move up to the creature's speed as long as the creature ends its movement next to the foe that was successfully attacked. This is *awfully* complicated, though. Probably better to stick with the feat **Travel Devotion** (*Complete Champion* 62-3) than try to work in tandem with a friendly demon with at-will *greater teleport* or whatever.
- Every other turn the tactical feat **Perfect Clarity of Mind and Body** (*Tome of Battle* 35), when the tactical maneuver coiled spring is employed, grants the creature a +30 ft. bonus to its land speed.
- The general feat **Sprinter** (*Dragon* #313 31-32) 3/day grants the creature the ability to gain a +10 ft. bonus to its speed for rounds equal to its Constitution bonus. One hopes the DM rules this is not an action to activate.
- If essentia can be rustled up, the general feat **Shape Soulmeld** (*cerulean sandals* (*Magic of Incarnum* 63)) (*Magic of Incarnum* 40) when so bound adds +5 ft. bonus/invested essentia to a creature's land speed. Other soulmelds have similar effects, but this one's earliest and available with the least (*ahem*) investment. Likewise, the similar feat **Sapphire Sprint** (*MoI* 40) if a creature somehow has more essentia than sense-ia. Thank you. Try the veal.

It's probably too difficult at this point to get the feats Cheetah Tribe Sprint (*ShS* 19), Divine Alacrity (*Faiths of Eberron* 145-6), Divine Vigor (*Red Hand of Doom* 126), Fire Feet (*Dragon* #311 40), Fury’s Focus (*Dragon* #304 84), Imbued Healing (*CC* 60) to use it with the domain Travel, Improved Power (Travel) (*Dragon* #342 21), Initiate of Fharlanghn (*Dragon* #342 51), Longstride Elite (*Races of Eberron* 114), Mark of Malbolge (*Fiendish Codex II* 84), Minor Shapeshift (*Complete Mage* 45), Prophecy’s Explorer (*Magic of Eberron* 50), Rage of the Raptor (*Dragon* #315 26), Speed of Thought (*Psionics Handbook* 29), Swiftness of Orien (*Player's Guide to Eberron* 48), Technomagic Implant (*Dragon* #351 93) for the *cheetah's swiftness* implant, and the trait Quick (*Unearthed Arcana* 89).

Unless shenanigans are used, Epic Speed (*Epic Level Handbook* 54) is likely unavailable, and it'll requires some serious persuasion to allow the psionic feat Psionic Boost (Expanding Your Mind Web column “New Talents, Feats, and More”).

Finally, it's probably too late to pick up the [regional feat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86588/8610) Fleet of Foot (*Player's Guide to Faerûn* 38), the dragon-only feat Improved Speed (*Dr* 71), or to be a saurian shifter with the shifter trait junglerunner (*Dragon* #328 63).

## *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* magic items that increase land speed

I'm pretty sure none grant enhancement bonuses so they should all be usable while the *expeditious retreat* spell's duration continues. This list is also alphabetical.

- A creature with at least two **air elemental grafts** gains a +5 ft. bonus to its land speed per graft beyond the first while unarmored or lightly armored and not carrying a weighty load. *Magic of Eberron* presents only four different air grafts, two probably conflicting (one taking up the flesh slot and another the skin slot).
- It's a little difficult to find a magic item enabling consistent use of a personal spell by a non-caster, especially seeing as how the skill Use Magic Device isn't a class skill for the swordsage or the [tenken](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Tenken,_Tome_(3.5e_Class)). Assuming the creature's not devoting cross-class ranks to the skill Use Magic Device, a handful of mildly distasteful options remain: the feat **Attune Gem** (*Magic of Faerûn* 21) creates at potion prices plus 50 gp per spell level gems that the user can crush as a standard action to cast such spells, and the feat Craft Wondrous Item allows the creation at potion prices ***spellworms*** (*Dragon* #343 80-1), an internal spell storing parasite that allows a spell to be used *either* as a standard action like a spell-like ability *or* as a full-round action like a spell (the text is contradictory). More palatable—and pricey—is something like a *ring of spell storing*, but this might involve more than is comfortable a friendly caster. Below I've assumed *spellworms* (and a standard action) because they're hilariously gross.

  - A ***spellworm of footsteps of the divine modified by the feat Extend Spell*** [trans] (*Complete Champion* 120-1) (3rd-level spell modified to a 4th-level spell at caster level 20) (*Dragon* #343 80-1) (4,000 gp; 0 lbs.) allows the creature to take a standard action to gain for 40 rounds a +50 ft. bonus to land speed by picking Fharlanghn or, if discharged, to gain for 1 round a +10 ft. bonus to land speed per round remaining in the spell's duration. Presumably, discharging the spell isn't an action, but ask the DM. This could net in the neighborhood of a +400 ft. bonus to the creature's land speed for 1 round.
  - A ***spellworm of greater celerity*** [trans] (*PH2* 105) (8th-level spell at caster level 15) (*Dragon* #343 80-1) (6,000 gp; 0 lbs.) allows a creature to take an immediate action to take a full-round action at the expense of being dazed for its next turn. If the DM agrees that a magic item that stores a spell can be activated using the same action as the spell's casting time, this can get the creature another extra turn.
- The ***belt of battle*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 73) (12,000 gp; 0 lbs.), in addition to granting the wearer a +2 competence bonus on initiative checks, allows the wearer to take a swift action to spend 1, 2, or 3 charges to gain a move, standard, or full-round action, respectively.
- A creature with the spellware enhancement ***boosted reflexes*** (*Dragon Annual* #6 52-3) (13,500 gp; 0 lbs.) gains a +2 enhancement bonus on Initiative checks and a +10 ft. bonus to speed.
- The best are the ***horned helm*** (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 133) (38,000 gp; 1 lb.) that, among other effects, doubles the wearer's base speed, and the [aforementioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87138/8610) magical shortspear ***rapid wrath*** (*Ghostwalk* 66) 11,702 gp; 3 lbs.) that, among other abilities, doubles the possessor's speed. These two items grant *any* creature a land speed of 120 ft.

Undoubtedly other sources of speed increases can dug up, but these are what I knew of off-hand. It's likely enough, but Dumpster-diving for even more is certainly a option.

### "How fast is that?"

Using just the resources in this answer—excluding bonuses from *expeditious retreat*, *haste*, and the homebrew base class, for instance—, consistently, this isn't as fast as you want, but, in a burst that expends a lot of resources for only 1 round, it's *way* faster than you need.

- Turn 1: Take standard action to activate wild shape to activate the feat **Cheetah's Speed**. That's a base speed of 50 ft. which the ***horned helmet*** doubles to 100 ft.
- Turn 2: Take a swift action to activate the feat **Animal Devotion**, picking cheetah's sprint. That's another +15 ft. for 65 ft. Take a standard action to activate the ***spellworm of footsteps of the divine***.
- Turn 3: Activate the feat **Sprinter** to gain for 1 turn a +10 ft. bonus to speed; this is not an action. Discharge the effect of the spell *footsteps of the divine* to gain for 1 round a +390 ft. bonus to speed (assuming an actual not relative duration); this is not an action. Take a full-round action to run. That's a speed of 515 ft. that's doubled *via* the magic weapon ***rapid wrath*** that's ×5 *via* the feat **Run** to 5,150 ft.

  Take a swift action to activate the ***belt of battle*** to gain an additional full-round action and take another full-round action to run. That's another 5,150 ft.

  Your turn should be over, but take an immediate action (spending the next turn's swift action) to activate the ***spellworm of greater celerity*** to take a third full-round action. On this full-round action, charge a foe, object, or square at ten times your speed *via* the feat Cheetah's Speed. That's another 10,300 ft. that's ×2 due to the maximum distance a creature can charge during a round.

This round, you've traveled 30,900 ft. in 6 seconds. That's about 3,500 mph, or over mach 4.5, which isn't even close to the [speed of light](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=kui28pclflv46krcm6c9lio4n1&topic=2548) but should be sufficient.

I don't want to get into Internet scuffles with anyone, so if it rubs you wrong to have activated the *spellworm of greater celerity* this way, skip that step and subtract 5,150 ft. from the total for, instead, about 2,900 mph or about a generous mach 4.

Note that *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* uses real-world multiplying for real-world things like speed (*PH* 304); [this is slightly different in *Pathfinder*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/gettingStarted.html#multiplying) but not much, but, as always, ask the DM.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be Mythic Adventures from pathfinder:

By selecting the champion/trickster path you open yourself up to the following:

> Fleet Charge (Ex) As a swift action, you can expend one use of mythic
>   power to move up to your speed...

Basically giving you twice your movement speed for a swift action.

> Impossible Speed: Your base land speed increases by 30 feet. In
>   addition, if you expend one use of mythic power, for 1 hour your base
>   land speed increases by 10 feet per mythic tier.

Maximum tier is 10, for a maximum of +130 movement speed.

There is also the mythic run feat, for 7 times your movement speed instead of 5 times (non-mythic run feat).

Let us move onto DnD 3.5:

Fleet of Foot feat ( Player's Guide to Faerun, p. 38): +10 untyped land speed.

Travel Devotion feat ( Complete Champion, p. 62) : swift action to move your speed.

Dash feat ( Complete Warrior, p. 97) : +5 to movement speed.